# Can I reasonably go five levels deep with a .Include in LINQ and a SQL Server 2012 Backend?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 5 with a SQL Server 2012 database and the following class structure. There are five levels to the structure:

Subject > Topic > SubTopic > Fact > Answers

What I need is to be able to get a list of Fact objects along with their Answers when the SubjectId is given to me. My concern here is performance and how deep I can go with a LINQ Query.

Here are the classes:

```
public partial class Subject {
    public Subject() { this.Topics = new List<Topic>(); }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}
public partial class Topic {
    public Topic() { this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>(); }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}
public partial class SubTopic {    
    public SubTopic() { this.Facts = new List<Fact>(); }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Fact> Facts { get; set; }     
}
public class Fact {
    public Fact() { this.Answers = new List<Answer>(); }      
    public int FactId { get; set; }
    public int FactStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubTopic SubTopic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Up until now all my LINQ Queries have been simple. For example here is the query I use to get facts when I know the subTopicId:

```
        var facts = _factsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(a => a.SubTopicId == subTopicId)
            .Include(a => a.Answers)
            .ToList();
```

Now I have a new requirement and I am not sure how to get the data that I need. What I need is to get a list of facts and the Answers that belong to a given SubjectId.

I would appreciate some advice and hope for some example code for this. Should I do something like the following:

```
        var facts = _subjectsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(a => a.SubjectId == subjectId)
```

and then do some long .Include list that includes Topic, SubTopic, Fact and finally Answers ?  Note that the data is used by administrators so although I need the data back quickly it does not need to be returned to me extremely fast.

Note that in the near future we hope to start working with EF6 and SQL Server 2014 previews. I would be interested to hear if anyone knows of any features these might bring that would help with our needs to get the data in this scenario.

Comment: You can, and it will be fast. Try it, measure it and if it's slow for your needs then try to split it in two or more queries.

Comment: Can you tell me how I need to code the .Include. If you could make just a few lines of that into an answer I could accept and try it out. I'm just not sure how to do the Include. Do I just chain one after the other?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want `Fact` entities and `Answer` entities then there is no point returning `Topic` and `Subtopic` entities too. Instead of getting the `Subject` entity and going 5 levels deep with the include. Something like below might do.

```
var query = context.Facts
                   .Where(f => f.Subtopic.Topic.SubjectId == mySubjectId)
                   .Include(f => f.Answers);
```